# Text in label not shown proper in window form

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, desktop-application

i work on one project in that i make my window from transparent. in that one label in that label text set by dynamically. after set the text it shown like below image.

[image: My Window Form]

in that `88` is the label which is set text by dynamically.

and the hello wo is try by me as a part of solution but it not work and it code is below.

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.Clear(Color.Empty);
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        g.DrawString("hello world", new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 48), Brushes.Blue, new Point(50, 50));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));
    }
```

but is also look like label text. 
`i want label text like clear type text please help me for it.`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
```

It will affect the performance

Answer (score 0):

Turn off AntiAliasing option in TextRenderingHint

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
```